# Fit plot in pdf page and issues related to BarH function

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a horizontal bar chart and facing 2 issues.

1. The labels on the y-axis are not fitting in the saved PDF page.
2. Values are not aligning in weirdly (neither ascending/descending)

Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd;
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import FigureCanvasPdf, PdfPages;
from matplotlib.figure import Figure;
import xlrd;
    #Only code part displaying plot is posted
    ax.set_title(titles,fontsize=5);
    ax.set_xlabel(vX[x],fontsize=5);
    ax.set_ylabel(vY[x],fontsize=5);
    ax.set_xticklabels(data2[vX[x]], rotation=45,ha='right');
    ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='major',labelsize=5);
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=5);
    ax.autoscale(enable=True);
    ax.plot(data2[vX[x]], data2[vY[x]],color=(clr[x]));
    canvas = FigureCanvasPdf(fig);
    canvas.print_figure(pages);
```

image for more clarity.

[image: Link]

Comment: I was able to resolve my first query using sub_plot.adjust() function in Matplotlib library. The second query still remains unsolved.